# twilio test credentials not making calls

Tags: php, post, twilio

I'm fairly new to Trilio and the whole REST API and I'm having some trouble trying to place calls via the test numbers that Trilio gave us.
My code (I followed the examples on the website), looks like this:

```
$testSID = "MY_TEST_SID";
$testToken  = "MY_TEST_TOKEN";
$testPhone = "+15005550006"; //valid number as defined by Trilio
$testResponse = "VALID PHONE"; //valid local phone number
client = new Services_Twilio($testSID, $testToken, "2010-04-01");
try 
{
     $call = $client->account->calls->create($testPhone, $testResponse, 
    "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml");
     echo $call->status;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

However whenever I run this php script, nothing happens. All i get is `queued` as the `$call->status`. The phone which I'm dialing doesn't ring either.

I know the Twilio docs say to POST the request to a URL, but from all the examples I've seen, the way I did it above seems to be the way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine and the test credentials are behaving exactly as designed. Here's the explanation from the help page.

> You use these credentials in the same way as your live credentials.
>   **However, when you authenticate with your test credentials, we will not
>   charge your account, update the state of your account, or connect to
>   real phone numbers.** You can now pretend to buy a phone number, or send
>   an SMS, without actually doing so.

Source: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials

So the test credentials will do everything *except* actually place the call or send the message. If you want your phone to ring, you'll have to use your normal credentials.

Comment: oh okay thanks!

I guess I skipped over that part when I first read over it.